# BitmapFactory.decodeFile always return null on Xiaomi

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

Hello I have this piece of code:

EDIT:

```
imageName = data.getData();

try{
    InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageName);

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream,null,options);

    final int REQUIRED_WIDTH=(int)screenWidth;
    final int REQUIRED_HIGHT=(int)screenHeight;

    int scale=1;
    while(options.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_WIDTH && options.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_HIGHT)
        scale*=2;

    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize=scale;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, o2);

    if ( bitmap != null ){
        ok=true;
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

But the bitmap is still null

Can Anyone tell me why ? or better... How to fix it ?

Comment: What is `getPathFromURI()`? If it is what I think it is, get rid of it, as [a `Uri` is not necessarily a `File`](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html).

Comment: I don't understand. I will add the method here

Comment: Delete that method. Read [the blog post that I linked to](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html). Use `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver` to read in the data at the `Uri`.

Comment: please check my updates

Comment: At this point, I have no idea what you are doing. If your objective is to get a `Bitmap` object on the data represented by the `Uri`, just pass `stream` to `decodeStream()` and get rid of `tmp`, the `ByteArrayOutputStream`, and the `ByteArrayInputStream`. Bear in mind that the image may be too big for your heap space.

Comment: Ok, so If I'll do it like it's now in edited post, how can I "resize" the image to get rid of outOfMemory Exception ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ok, so If I'll do it like it's now in edited post, how can I "resize" the image to get rid of outOfMemory Exception ?

Aha! Now we are getting somewhere.

What you had, in a prior edit of your question, was:

1. read the entire bitmap into a byte array
2. write the entire bitmap into another byte array as a low-quality JPEG
3. read the entire bitmap into a `Bitmap`, backed by yet a third byte array

This will result in your consuming ~2.1x the heap space of your current implementation, which is already giving you `OutOfMemoryError` messages. The byte arrays from #1 and #3 above will be the same size, equal to:

```
width x height x 4
```

where the width and height are expressed in pixels.

To reduce your memory consumption, you need to do to things:

1. Read in the bitmap **once**, as your current code does.
2. Use `BitmapFactory.Options` to control the decoding of the bitmap. In particular, [use `inSampleSize`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) to reduce the number of pixels in the resulting `Bitmap`. Quoting the JavaDocs for `inSampleSize`:

> If set to a value > 1, requests the decoder to subsample the original image, returning a smaller image to save memory. The sample size is the number of pixels in either dimension that correspond to a single pixel in the decoded bitmap. For example, inSampleSize == 4 returns an image that is 1/4 the width/height of the original, and 1/16 the number of pixels. Any value <= 1 is treated the same as 1. Note: the decoder uses a final value based on powers of 2, any other value will be rounded down to the nearest power of 2.

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Bitmaps/InSampleSize) demonstrates the use of `inSampleSize` for various hardcoded values. The actual `Bitmap` loading comes from:

```
private Bitmap load(String path, int inSampleSize) throws IOException {
  BitmapFactory.Options opts=new BitmapFactory.Options();

  opts.inSampleSize=inSampleSize;

  return(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assets().open(path), null, opts));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your getPathFromUri method is failing.  It should be returning something like `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/camera/bla bla.jpg`.  The `file://` is the authority and isn't part of the path.  BitmapFactory is looking for an actual file location path.

You can strip that manually or use [Uri](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html) class with something like this:

```
Uri imgUri = Uri.parse(imgPath);
String filePath = imgUri.getPath();
```

Comment: Stil not working... now the file:/// is gone but still getting null