# Get file path from URI

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I have Uri for Image file.

I use this code for gets file path from Uri:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.message(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

If I choose image from Gallery app(Android 4.4.2, arm-emu),

```
uri.getPath = /external/images/media/16 and it work's fine (My file path: /storage/sdcard/Download/0_cf15a_7800a7e5_orig.jpg)
```

If I choose image from Documents app(Android 4.4.2, arm-emu),

```
 I have uri.getPath = /document/image:16 and function getRealPathFromURI returns null.
```

How I can return correct path to file for boths action?

**My Code Is:-**

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Photohunt" + File.separator);
        root.mkdirs();
        final String fname = Common.getUniqueImageFilename();
        final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, fname);
        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
            // Camera.
            final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
            final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            final PackageManager packageManager = mContext.getPackageManager();
            final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
            for(ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
                final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
                final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
                intent.setPackage(packageName);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
                cameraIntents.add(intent);
            }

            // Filesystem.
            final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

            // Chooser of filesystem options.
            final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");

            // Add the camera options.
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));

            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

Handle activity result:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        if(requestCode == PICTURE_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            final boolean isCamera;
            if(data == null)
            {
                isCamera = true;
            }
            else
            {
                final String action = data.getAction();
                if(action == null)
                {
                    isCamera = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    isCamera = action.equals(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }
            }

            Uri selectedImageUri;
            if(isCamera)
            {
                selectedImageUri = outputFileUri;
            }
            else
            {
                selectedImageUri = data == null ? null : data.getData();
            }

            Log.variable("uri", selectedImageUri.getPath());
            ConfirmImageFragment fragment = new ConfirmImageFragment(selectedImageUri, mContestId);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Loading selected file into ImageView works fine for both state:

```
private void loadImage() {
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(mContext.getContentResolver(), mUri);
        mImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Solution:

```
    public class RealPathUtil {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getRealPathFromURI_API19(Context context, Uri uri){
        String filePath = "";
        String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

         // Split at colon, use second item in the array
         String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

         String[] column = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };     

         // where id is equal to             
         String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

         Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
                                   column, sel, new String[]{ id }, null);

         int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

         if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
             filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
         }   
         cursor.close();
         return filePath;
    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static String getRealPathFromURI_API11to18(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
          String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
          String result = null;

          CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
                  context, 
            contentUri, proj, null, null, null);        
          Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

          if(cursor != null){
           int column_index = 
             cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
           cursor.moveToFirst();
           result = cursor.getString(column_index);
          }
          return result;  
    }

    public static String getRealPathFromURI_BelowAPI11(Context context, Uri contentUri){
               String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
               Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
               int column_index
          = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
               cursor.moveToFirst();
               return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
}
```

http://hmkcode.com/android-display-selected-image-and-its-real-path/

Comment: DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri); its not resolved, how to organize import of DocumentsContract

Comment: How do you implement this for non-image files?

Comment: Jesus. Android APIs are so terrible.

Comment: Doesn't even work. Using standard Gallery app on Samsung S2.

Comment: @Artem Tried code for Kitkat and above. Not working for URI : content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A63829. For which I selected this image from file selector in motorola nexus 6

Comment: it just works for media. how about any file ? uri like this : "/document/135"

Answer (score 2):

A simpler version of the accepted answer that will detect the API level and use the correct method :

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public static String getFilePath(Context context, Uri uri)
{
    int currentApiVersion;
    try
    {
         currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        //API 3 will crash if SDK_INT is called
        currentApiVersion = 3;
    }
    if (currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    {
        String filePath = "";
        String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

        // Split at colon, use second item in the array
        String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

        String[] column = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        // where id is equal to
        String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                column, sel, new String[]{id}, null);

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        }
        cursor.close();
        return filePath;
    }
    else if (currentApiVersion <= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2 && currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)

    {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        String result = null;

        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(
                context,
                uri, proj, null, null, null);
        Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

        if (cursor != null)
        {
            int column_index =
                    cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            result = cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        return result;
    }
    else
    {

        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index
                = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you implement this for non-image files?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution, using all tricks I've found so far, which I use on my own app too ([**here**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager)) :

**FileUtilEx.kt**

```
fun Closeable?.closeSilently() {
    if (this != null) try {
        this.close()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
    }
}

object FileUtilEx {
    fun getFilePathFromUri(context: Context, uri: Uri, includeUriMappingTechnique: Boolean = true, tryToGetWritePermission: Boolean = false): ClosableFileHolder? {
        var file: File
        uri.path?.let {
            file = File(it)
            if (file.exists() && file.canRead()) {
//                Log.d("AppLog", "got real file")
                return ClosableFileHolder(file)
            }
        }
        if (uri.scheme == "file") {
            try {
                val jUri = java.net.URI(uri.scheme, uri.schemeSpecificPart, uri.fragment)
                file = File(jUri)
                if (file.exists() && file.canRead()) {
//                    Log.d("AppLog", "got real file")
                    return ClosableFileHolder(file)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
            }
            try {
                val uriStr = uri.toString()
                val decodePath = URLDecoder.decode(uriStr, "UTF-8")
                file = File(decodePath)
                if (file.exists() && file.canRead()) {
//                    Log.d("AppLog", "got real file")
                    return ClosableFileHolder(file)
                }
            } catch (e: UnsupportedEncodingException) {
            }
        }
        val authority = uri.authority
        if (uri.scheme == "content") {
            //handles "Files" app, and many others
            getRealPathFromUri(context, uri)?.let {
                file = File(it)
                if (file.exists() && file.canRead()) {
//                    Log.d("AppLog", "got real file")
                    return ClosableFileHolder(file)
                }
            }
        }
        if (includeUriMappingTechnique) {
            val fileUsingUriMappingTechnique = getFileUsingUriMappingTechnique(context, uri, tryToGetWritePermission)
            if (fileUsingUriMappingTechnique != null)
                return fileUsingUriMappingTechnique
        }
        getFilePathFromDocumentUri(context, uri)?.let { filePath ->
            file = File(filePath)
            if (file.exists() && file.canRead())
                return ClosableFileHolder(file)
        }
        return null
    }


    private fun getRealPathFromUri(context: Context, contentUri: Uri): String? {
        try {
            context.contentResolver.query(contentUri, arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA), null, null, null)?.use { cursor ->
                val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
                if (columnIndex < 0 || cursor.count <= 0)
                    return null
                cursor.moveToFirst()
                return cursor.getString(columnIndex)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return null
    }

    fun getFileUsingUriMappingTechnique(context: Context, androidUri: Uri, tryToGetWritePermission: Boolean = false): ClosableFileHolder? {
        var parcelFileDescriptor: ParcelFileDescriptor? = null
        for (i in 0..1)
            try {
                parcelFileDescriptor = context.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(androidUri, if (tryToGetWritePermission && i == 0) "w" else "r")
                if (parcelFileDescriptor != null) {
                    val fd: Int = parcelFileDescriptor.fd
                    val linkFileName = "/proc/self/fd/$fd"
                    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.O) {
                        val realFilePath = Files.readSymbolicLink(Paths.get(linkFileName))
                        val file = realFilePath.toFile()
                        if (file.exists() && file.canRead()) {
                            parcelFileDescriptor.closeSilently()
                            return ClosableFileHolder(file)
                        }
                    }
                    val file = File(linkFileName)
                    if (file.exists() && file.canRead())
                        return ClosableFileHolder(file, parcelFileDescriptor)
                    parcelFileDescriptor.closeSilently()
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                parcelFileDescriptor.closeSilently()
                parcelFileDescriptor = null
            }
        return null
    }

    private fun getFilePathFromDocumentUri(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
        //            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657411/android-getting-a-file-uri-from-a-content-uri
        // DocumentProvider
        if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && DocumentFile.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if ("com.android.externalstorage.documents" == uri.authority) {
                val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
                val split = docId.split(":".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
                val type = split[0]
                // This is for checking Main Memory
                return if ("primary".equals(type, ignoreCase = true)) {
                    if (split.size > 1) {
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + "/" + split[1] + "/"
                    } else {
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + "/"
                    }
                    // This is for checking SD Card
                } else {
                    "storage" + "/" + docId.replace(":", "/")
                }
            }
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

**ClosableFileHolder.kt**

```
class ClosableFileHolder(val file: File, private val parcelFileDescriptor: ParcelFileDescriptor? = null) : Closeable {

    fun isUsingUriMappingTechnique(): Boolean = parcelFileDescriptor != null

    override fun close() {
        parcelFileDescriptor.closeSilently()
    }

    protected fun finalize() {
        parcelFileDescriptor.closeSilently()
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
FileUtilEx.getFilePathFromUri(context, uri, false)?.use {
    val file = it.file
    ...
}
```

The `tryToGetWritePermission` parameter is in case you want to access the file, but it's in fact not available normally (like in SAF), so it's offered you in a different place. This is useful in case you want to access the file but don't care where it really exists.

Comment: Great, It is working in all types of test cases. Thanks.

Comment: @VishalThakkar Can you please check it in special cases, such as SD-card? I tried to use all the things I could...

Comment: i don't have device with SD card. BTW can you provide above code in java?

Comment: @VishalThakkar Java would be similar. You can call these functions via Java, too. No need to convert.

Comment: how can i call this in the java? as i know extension functions can not be called in the java.

Comment: There is no extension function that you need to call here (also BTW you can call them, just more annoying). Look at the part of "usage" that I wrote ...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you give permission in Manifest.
Wasted 2 hours trying various methods without giving permissions :/

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. A generalized code for getting URI from path :

```
String path = yourAndroidURI.uri.getPath()
File file = new File(new URI(path));
```

Comment: Exception: URI is not absolute: /document/image:16

Answer (score 0):

So I tried basically ever answer on the stack but this was the only one that worked for me.  It is important to think about the uri as a "promise" that an image lives where it points to.  This does not mean there is a file at that location but if you ask correctly you will get an image. attachementPath is the path to the image (can be used like a regular file). See below:

```
try {
            InputStream input = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            File file = new File(getActivity().getCacheDir(), "cacheFileAppeal.png");
            try {

                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
                try {
                    try {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024]; // or other buffer size
                        int read;

                        if (input != null) {
                            while ((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                output.write(buffer, 0, read);
                            }
                        }
                        output.flush();
                    } finally {
                        output.close();
                        attachmentPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(); // handle exception, define IOException and others
                }

            } finally {
                try {
                    if (input != null) {
                        input.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

public static int getIdFromUri(Uri uri, String constantId)
    {
        Cursor c = ContentMaster.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]{constantId}, null, null, null);

```
    int res = -1;
    if(c != null && c.getCount() > 0)
    {
        c.moveToFirst();
        res = c.getInt(0);
        c.close();
    }
    return res;
}
public static Uri getUriWithId(Uri baseUri,int contactId)
{
    Uri u = ContentUris.withAppendedId(baseUri, contactId);

    if(u != null)
        return u;

    return Uri.EMPTY;
}
public static String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri)
{
    if(uri == null)
        return "";

    if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme()))
        return uri.getPath();


    String[] pro = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    String result = null;
    Cursor cursor;

    if(VERSION.SDK_INT > 18)
    {
        //String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
        //String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];
        String id = String.valueOf(getIdFromUri(uri, Images.Media._ID));
        String[] column = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        String where = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";
        Uri u = uri;

        if(isMediaDocument(uri))
        {
            if (getUriMediaDocumentType(uri).equals("image"))
            {
                if(isExternalStorageDocument(uri))
                    u = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                else
                    u = MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }
            else if (getUriMediaDocumentType(uri).equals("video"))
            {
                if(isExternalStorageDocument(uri))
                    u = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                else
                    u = MediaStore.Video.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }
            else if (getUriMediaDocumentType(uri).equals("audio"))
            {
                if(isExternalStorageDocument(uri))
                    u = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                else
                    u = MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }
        }
        else if(isDownloadsDocument(uri))
        {
            u = getUriWithId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Integer.getInteger(id));
        }

        cursor = getContentResolver().query(u, column, where, new String[]{id}, null);
    }
    else if(VERSION.SDK_INT > 10)
    {
        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(SystemMaster.getContext(), uri, pro, null, null, null);
        cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
    }
    else
    {
        cursor = SystemMaster.getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, pro, null, null, null);
    }


    if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0)
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        cursor.close();
    }

    return result;
}

public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri)
{
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri)
{
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri)
{
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public static String getUriMediaDocumentType(Uri uri)
{
    if(isMediaDocument(uri))
    {
       //TODO
        return "image";
    }

    return "";
}
```