# Android - Get file path from URI gives error

Tags: android, image

I am trying to get file path of an image from `URI`, but I am getting this `error`:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI: content://media/external/images/media/9298
   at android.provider.DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(DocumentsContract.java:917)
```

Here is the function that saves the image:

```
public Uri saveImage(Context context, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(context.getContentResolver(),
            inImage,
            DateTimeUtil.getDateTime(),
            null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

And here is the function that reads the file path of the image:

```
public String getFilePathFromURI(Context context, Uri uri){
    String filePath = "";

    String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri); <<<<<< ERROR HERE

    // Split at colon, use second item in the array
    String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

    String[] column = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    // where id is equal to
    String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            column, sel, new String[]{ id }, null);

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    }
    cursor.close();


    return filePath;
}
```

Comment: This might help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61835665/878126