# Accessing public download files onActivityResult Android 28 Samsung Galaxy S9+ (Verizon)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions, android-storage

> > ---
> >
> > UPDATE
>
> I have a Samsung Galaxy S8+ running 8.0.0 T-Mobile  that it works fine on running
>    8.0.0
>
> My Samsung Galaxy S9+ running 8.0.0 Verizon, it fails everytime with illegal argument.
>
> My Samsung Galaxy S9+ running 8.0.0 T-Mobile has no issues and works fine
>
> So this may be OEM specific model issue, but not
>   sure how to fix it yet. I have also tried rebooting the Phone, no
>   change in outcome.
>
> Also, I opened the public downloads from within Evernote and saved the
>   file as an attachment to a Note, which tells me that Evernote is able
>   to access the public directory just fine and attach the file, so it is
>   possible to do on the device. Leading me to believe it is code
>   related.
>
> > ---

So I've recently upgraded a project that was working just fine and it now has a bug now that it is compiling with build tools 28, for the latest version of Android.

So I have always used this PathUtil to get the file path I needed from an implicit intent to get file selection from the user. I'll share a link to the code that I am using for a long time now below.

[PathUtil](https://gist.github.com/tatocaster/32aad15f6e0c50311626)

It's just a utility class that checks the provider authority and gets the absolute path for the file you are attempting to read.

When the user selects a file from the public downloads directory it returns to **onActivityResult** with:

```
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/2025
```

Now the nice utility parses this out and tells me that this is a download directory file and is a document with id 2025. Thanks utility, that's a great start.

> Next up is to use the content resolver to find the file absolute path.
>   This is what used to work, but no longer does :(.

Now the path utility simply uses the contract data that they most likely got from the core library themselves. I tried to import the provider class to avoid static strings, but it doesn't seem to be available, so I guess simply using matching strings is the best way to go for now.

Here is the core DownloadProvider for reference that is providing all the access for the content resolver. 
[DownloadProvider](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/DownloadProvider/+/master/src/com/android/providers/downloads/DownloadProvider.java)

> NOTE* This DownloadProvider is Androids, not mine

Here is the code that builds the Uri for the contentProvider

```
 val id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
 val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse(PUBLIC_DOWNLOAD_PATH), id.toLong())
 return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null)
```

the call references:

```
    private fun getDataColumn(context: Context, uri: Uri, selection: String?, selectionArgs: Array<String>?): String? {
        var cursor: Cursor? = null
        val column = "_data"
        val projection = arrayOf(column)
        try {
            cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null)
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                val column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column)
                return cursor.getString(column_index)
            }
        }catch (ex: Exception){
            A35Log.e("PathUtils", "Error getting uri for cursor to read file: ${ex.message}")
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close()
        }
        return null
    }
```

Essentially the contentUri to be resolved ends up being

> content://downloads/public_downloads/2025

Then when you call the query method it throws:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI: content://downloads/public_downloads/2025

Things I've confirmed or tried

1. Read external permissions (comes with write, but did it anyway)
2. Write external permissions
3. Permissions are in manifest and retrieved at runtime
4. I've selected multiple different files to see if one is weird
5. I've confirmed permissions are granted in application settings
6. I've hard coded the Uri to /1 or even /#2052 on the end to try various ending types
7. I've researched the uriMatching on the core library to look for how it expects it to be formatted and ensured it matches
8. I've played around with all_downloads directory in the uri and that resolves!!, but with security exception so the resolver must exist.

I don't know what else to try, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I still have to do some backwards compatible testing, but I have successfully resolved my own problem after many hours of trial and error.

How I resolved it was to modify the isDownloadDirectory path flow of getPath. I don't know all the ripple effects yet though as QA will be starting on it tomorrow, i'll update if I learn anything new from this.

Use the direct URI to get the contentResolver for file name (NOTE* This is not a good way to get file name unless you are certain it is a local file according to Google, but for me, I am certain it is downloaded.)

Then next use the Environment external public download constants combined with the returned content resolver name to get your absolute path. The new code looks like this.

```
private val PUBLIC_DOWNLOAD_PATH = "content://downloads/public_downloads"
private val EXTERNAL_STORAGE_DOCUMENTS_PATH = "com.android.externalstorage.documents"
private val DOWNLOAD_DOCUMENTS_PATH = "com.android.providers.downloads.documents"
private val MEDIA_DOCUMENTS_PATH = "com.android.providers.media.documents"
private val PHOTO_CONTENTS_PATH = "com.google.android.apps.photos.content"

//HELPER METHODS
    private fun isExternalStorageDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return EXTERNAL_STORAGE_DOCUMENTS_PATH == uri.authority
    }
    private fun isDownloadsDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return DOWNLOAD_DOCUMENTS_PATH == uri.authority
    }
    private fun isMediaDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return MEDIA_DOCUMENTS_PATH == uri.authority
    }
    private fun isGooglePhotosUri(uri: Uri): Boolean {
        return PHOTO_CONTENTS_PATH == uri.authority
    }

 fun getPath(context: Context, uri: Uri): String? {
    if (DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
            val split = docId.split(COLON.toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
            val type = split[0]
            val storageDefinition: String
            if (PRIMARY_LABEL.equals(type, ignoreCase = true)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + FORWARD_SLASH + split[1]
            } else {
                if (Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()) {
                    storageDefinition = EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                } else {
                    storageDefinition = SECONDARY_STORAGE
                }
                return System.getenv(storageDefinition) + FORWARD_SLASH + split[1]
            }
        } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
            //val id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri) //MAY HAVE TO USE FOR OLDER PHONES, HAVE TO TEST WITH REGRESSION MODELS
            //val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse(PUBLIC_DOWNLOAD_PATH), id.toLong()) //SAME NOTE AS ABOVE
            val fileName = getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null)
            var uriToReturn: String? = null
            if(fileName != null){
                uriToReturn = Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).absolutePath), fileName).toString()
            }
            return uriToReturn
        } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri)
            val split = docId.split(COLON.toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
            val type = split[0]
            var contentUri: Uri? = null
            if (IMAGE_PATH == type) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            } else if (VIDEO_PATH == type) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            } else if (AUDIO_PATH == type) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
            }
            val selection = "_id=?"
            val selectionArgs = arrayOf(split[1])
            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri!!, selection, selectionArgs)
        }
    } else if (CONTENT.equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true)) {
        return if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri)) uri.lastPathSegment else getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null)
    } else if (FILE.equals(uri.scheme, ignoreCase = true)) {
        return uri.path
    }
    return null
}




    private fun getDataColumn(context: Context, uri: Uri, selection: String?, selectionArgs: Array<String>?): String? {
        var cursor: Cursor? = null
        //val column = "_data" REMOVED IN FAVOR OF NULL FOR ALL   
        //val projection = arrayOf(column) REMOVED IN FAVOR OF PROJECTION FOR ALL 
        try {
            cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, null, selection, selectionArgs, null)
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME) //_display_name
                return cursor.getString(columnIndex) //returns file name
            }
        }catch (ex: Exception){
            A35Log.e(SSGlobals.SEARCH_STRING + "PathUtils", "Error getting uri for cursor to read file: ${ex.message}")
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close()
        }
        return null
    }
```

Comment: It's all there, just scroll inside the gray window.

Comment: can you please provide it in java?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Sam.

I do it's help of @Sam answer in java.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.DocumentsContract;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Switch;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Objects;

import kotlin.Metadata;
import kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt;
import kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics;
import kotlin.text.Regex;
import kotlin.text.StringsKt;

public class UtilsFile {


    private final static String PUBLIC_DOWNLOAD_PATH = "content://downloads/public_downloads";


    private final static String EXTERNAL_STORAGE_DOCUMENTS_PATH = "com.android.externalstorage.documents";


    private final static String DOWNLOAD_DOCUMENTS_PATH = "com.android.providers.downloads.documents";


    private final static String MEDIA_DOCUMENTS_PATH = "com.android.providers.media.documents";


    private final static String PHOTO_CONTENTS_PATH = "com.google.android.apps.photos.content";


    private Boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return EXTERNAL_STORAGE_DOCUMENTS_PATH.equals(uri.getAuthority());

    }
 private Boolean isPublicDocument(Uri uri) {
        return PUBLIC_DOWNLOAD_PATH.equals(uri.getAuthority());

    }


    private Boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return DOWNLOAD_DOCUMENTS_PATH.equals(uri.getAuthority());

    }

    private Boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return MEDIA_DOCUMENTS_PATH.equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }


    private Boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return MEDIA_DOCUMENTS_PATH.equals(uri.getAuthority());

    }
 private Boolean isPhotoContentUri(Uri uri) {
        return PHOTO_CONTENTS_PATH.equals(uri.getAuthority());

    }



    private String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

        Cursor cursor = null;
        //String column = "_data" REMOVED IN FAVOR OF NULL FOR ALL
        //String projection = arrayOf(column) REMOVED IN FAVOR OF PROJECTION FOR ALL
        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, selection, selectionArgs, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DocumentsContract.Document.COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME);
                return cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("PathUtils", "Error getting uri for cursor to read file: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            assert cursor != null;
            cursor.close();
        }
        return null;

    }

    public  String getFullPathFromContentUri(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
        String filePath="";
        // DocumentProvider
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            // ExternalStorageProvider
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }//non-primary e.g sd card
                else {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 20) {
                        //getExternalMediaDirs() added in API 21
                        File[] extenal = context.getExternalMediaDirs();
                        for (File f : extenal) {
                            filePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
                            if (filePath.contains(type)) {
                                int endIndex = filePath.indexOf("Android");
                                filePath = filePath.substring(0, endIndex) + split[1];
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        filePath = "/storage/" + type + "/" + split[1];
                    }
                    return filePath;
                }
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                String fileName = getDataColumn(context,  uri,null, null);
                String uriToReturn = null;
                if (fileName != null) {
                    uriToReturn = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                            Uri.parse(
                                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath()), fileName
                    ).toString();
                }
                return uriToReturn;
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        split[1]
                };

                Cursor cursor = null;
                final String column = "_data";
                final String[] projection = {
                        column
                };

                try {
                    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                            null);
                    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                        return cursor.getString(column_index);
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (cursor != null)
                        cursor.close();
                }
                return null;
            }

        }
        // MediaStore (and general)
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        // File
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
        else if (isPublicDocument(uri)){
            String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse(PUBLIC_DOWNLOAD_PATH), Long.parseLong(id));
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            @SuppressLint("Recycle") Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, projection, null, null, null);

            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: you missing one change in this file you need to use "contentUri" this variable so change and update the answer else all working fine Thank you

Answer (score 1):

My solution was different
I was trying to get the path so I can copy the file to my application folder.
After not finding the answer I tried the following approach.
I use Xamarin Forms

```
           // DownloadsProvider
            else if (IsDownloadsDocument(uri))
            {
                if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
                {
                    //Hot fix for android oreo
                    bool res = MediaService.MoveAssetFromURI(uri, ctx, ref error);
                    return res ? "copied" : null;
                }
                else
                {
                    string id = DocumentsContract.GetDocumentId(uri);

                    Android.Net.Uri contentUri = ContentUris.WithAppendedId(
                                    Android.Net.Uri.Parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), long.Parse(id));

                    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(contentUri.ToString());

                    return GetDataColumn(ctx, contentUri, null, null);
                }
            }

 public static bool MoveAssetFromURI(Android.Net.Uri uri, Context ctx, ref string error)
    {           
        string directory = PhotoApp.App.LastPictureFolder;

        var type = ctx.ContentResolver.GetType(uri);

        string assetName = FileName(ctx, uri);

        string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(assetName);

        var filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(assetName);

        var finalPath = $"{directory}/{filename}{extension}";

        if (File.Exists(finalPath))
        {
            error = "File already exists at the destination";
            return false;
        }

        if (extension != ".pdf" && extension == ".jpg" && extension == ".png")
        {
            error = "File extension not suported";
            return false;
        }

        using (var input = ctx.ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(uri))
        {
            using (var fileStream = File.Create(finalPath))
            {
                //input.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                input.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
        }

        if (extension == ".pdf")
        {
            var imagePDFIcon = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(ctx.Resources, Resource.Drawable.icon_pdf);

            var imagePDFPortrait = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(ctx.Resources, Resource.Drawable.pdf_image);

            using (var stream = new FileStream($"{directory}/{filename}", FileMode.Create))
            {
                imagePDFIcon.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 90, stream);
            }

            using (var stream = new FileStream($"{directory}/{filename}.jpg", FileMode.Create))
            {
                imagePDFPortrait.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 90, stream);
            }

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (extension == ".jpg" || extension == ".png")
            {
                MoveImageFromGallery(finalPath);

                File.Delete(finalPath);

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
```

So instead of trying to get the path I created an input stream and copied the stream to the location I wanted.
Hope this helps

Comment: Note that my logic is a little bit custom. I need to copy a PDF from download folder but I also create a thumbnail and a pic to display it in my app

Comment: Thanks for sharing @Vasily but the question was revolving around native development not .NET. I'll leave the answer there as maybe it will help someone else that visits here from Xamarin needs, but doesn't help me. Although, I've already solved my own issue.

Comment: ok, but I have worked with both and you will be amazed how similar they are. Sometimes my only source is native and I have to port

Comment: Makes sense, and you are correct there are similar nomenclature as Xamarin does a good job of matching native naming conventions. I noticed your directory paths were similar to mine as well. Like i said, it may help someone in the Xamarin community, so it doesn't hurt to leave it there.