# how to get absolute path from pick file in android device?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

i try many way but intent not return path that i want , how can i get absolute path ?

this is which i retrieved

```
/document/image:29163
```

code for intent

```
  binding.buttonSetVoiceGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("*/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });
```

when activityresult

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Log.d(TAG,data.getData().getPath());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use the uri directly. There is no need to try to get a file system path..

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26196374/10357086

Answer (score 1):

```
 binding.buttonSetVoiceGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
            
   Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            launcher.launch(intent);
                }
            });

 ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> launcher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK ) {
                   Intent data = result.getData();
                    Uri uri= data.getData();
                     File file = new File(FileMyutils.getPath(getContext(),uri));    
                    }
                }
            });





public class FileMyutils {
    private static final String TAG = "FileUtils";
    @WorkerThread
    @Nullable
    public static String getReadablePathFromUri(Context context, Uri uri) {

        String path = null;
        if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            path = uri.getPath();
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            path = getPath(context, uri);
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
            return path;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "get path from uri: " + path);
        if (!isReadablePath(path)) {
            int index = path.lastIndexOf("/");
            String name = path.substring(index + 1);
            String dstPath = context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + name;
            if (copyFile(context, uri, dstPath)) {
                path = dstPath;
                Log.d(TAG, "copy file success: " + path);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "copy file fail!");
            }
        }
        return path;
    }

    public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {
        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                Log.d("External Storage", docId);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }
            } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

                String dstPath = context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + getFileName(context,uri);

                if (copyFile(context, uri, dstPath)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "copy file success: " + dstPath);
                    return dstPath;

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "copy file fail!");
                }


            } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{split[1]};
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        } else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String getFileName(Context context, Uri uri) {

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri,null,null,null,null);
        int nameindex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        return  cursor.getString(nameindex);
    }


    private static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                        String[] selectionArgs) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {column};

        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private static boolean isReadablePath(@Nullable String path) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
            return false;
        }
        boolean isLocalPath;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
                File localFile = new File(path);
                isLocalPath = localFile.exists() && localFile.canRead();
            } else {
                isLocalPath = false;
            }
        } else {
            isLocalPath = path.startsWith(File.separator);
        }
        return isLocalPath;
    }

    private static boolean copyFile(Context context, Uri uri, String dstPath) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(dstPath);

            byte[] buff = new byte[100 * 1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = inputStream.read(buff)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buff, 0, len);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (outputStream != null) {
                try {
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code for getting absolute path:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Log.d(TAG,data.getData().getPath());
            Object objImg = data.getExtras().get("path");
            Log.e("Selected", "" + objImg.toString());
            /*--getting image uri from object--*/
            Uri selectedImage = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(objImg));
            Log.e("Selected Image", "" + selectedImage);
            /*--create file object using uri--*/
            File myFile = new File(selectedImage.getPath());
            String path = myFile.getAbsolutePath();
            Log.e("AbsolutePath---", ""+path);
        }
    }
```